# How does "Do not track" in Google Chrome work?

Tags: google-chrome, tracking

I have recently found a do not track checkbox in my chrome options.

Nevertheless it is pretty obvious what it is going to do, I have a question regarding how it is going to do this and what is the probability that this checkbox will work.

First of all the idea behind the "Do Not Track": a browser is going to include something which is telling the server not to track your identity and not to use your previous history to show you ads.
After checking this checkbox I was not able to find any difference in request headers or request uri sent to the server. So the question is how is the browser sending this information. Also what I am as a developer should do to correctly respond to such request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should see a header named "DNT" sent to the server with all your requests. It's possible you will need to restart your browser before it starts being sent.

Here's an image from Chrome's developer tools. You can access this in your own browser by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> then selecting the network tab and selecting the first item in the list (You will need to refresh the page with the Developer tools open before anything will appear).

[image: Do Not Track Header]

As a developer there isn't (AFAIK) any set standard on what you need to do when seeing such a request. Generally if you have any user tracking implemented and detect that DNT is set to 1 you should disable it, but your technically not required to honour it at all.

Comment: That last sentence is especially important. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_Not_Track#Effectiveness) for more.

Comment: thanks. Actually I need to restart a browser. I found it later by myself.